# How to make a cluster of 4 desktops

Tags: failover, cluster-computing

Hi I have 4 desktop computers with dual core processors, 500GB disk and 3GB of RAM which I am using as build servers. I would like to create a cluster of these 4 computers so that these four desktop computers act as one server.

Comment: Have you looked at TeamCity ? It wouldn't act as one server, rather one server and four build machine grid.  The server doesn't need all that much power. http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/the_build_grid.html

Comment: I am looking for an opensource solution. From my understanding TeamCity is a commercial solution. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You are correct it's commercial.  It's free to use unless you need more than 3 build computers then there are some license fees involved.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you look at continuous integration tools, such as [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/), which handles distributed builds in a way that seems to be consistent with what you're looking for. Also, even though it is a Java-based framework, it is not limited to Java build tools like ANt or Maven, it also handles shell scripts and native tools like make.